# Utilizing a current web site's assets in a new mobile version

Tags: integration, mobile-website

I recently joined a friend of mine in developing his web app. He built it from scratch using the MVC pattern.

Now I'm trying to make a new (and separated in a sub domain) mobile site that's based on CodeIgniter, but I have no idea how to utilize the models my friend made, especially considering they don't follow CodeIgniter's rules, plus they have includes and dependencies on other files in them.

Any suggestions on how I could approach this?

Your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your friend used the MVC pattern to develop the initial site, why not re-use his controller/model to serve up different views.

That way you're not re-writing code, messing with new frameworks, worrying about incompatibilities, etc. You just have to make the new views handle the data and look pretty on a mobile device.

Comment: but the mobile site is going to be in a sub-domain. How would that work?